# syncfusion Grid is not displayed on screen

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, grid, syncfusion

I am trying to build my Data set on a syncfusion Grid using an MVC app. The code is executed properly without any errors but the Grid is not displayed on the screen.

My Controller will look like as below:

```
        public ActionResult PieT(FormCollection form)
        {


            MvcApplication2.Models.FMSData FMS1 = new MvcApplication2.Models.FMSData("100", "200");
             MvcApplication2.Models.FMSData FMS2=new MvcApplication2.Models.FMSData("10", "20");
             MvcApplication2.Models.FMSDatas FMSCollection = new MvcApplication2.Models.FMSDatas();
            FMSCollection.add(FMS1);
            FMSCollection.add(FMS2);
            ViewBag.DataSource = FMSCollection.FMSArray.ToList();
            return View();
        }
```

The view looks like as below:

```
    @{
    Layout = null;
    }
    @using MvcApplication2.Models
    @using MvcApplication2.ViewModels
    @using Syncfusion.JavaScript.DataVisualization
    @using System.Collections
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>PieT</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>@using (Html.BeginForm("PieT", "Pie", FormMethod.Post))
        {
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Month</td>

            <td>  @Html.DropDownList("Months", ViewData["Months"] as SelectList, "--Select Months--") </td> 

            <td>
                Year</td>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownList("Year") </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </td>

</tr>
    </table>
        }
           </div>@(Html.EJ().Grid<FMSData>("FlatGrid")
        .Datasource((IEnumerable<object>)ViewBag.datasource)
        .SelectionType(SelectionType.Single)

        .Columns(col =>
        {
            col.Field("TotalDistance").HeaderText("Total Distance Travelled").IsPrimaryKey(true).TextAlign(TextAlign.Right).Width(75).Add();
            col.Field("TotalFuelConsumed").HeaderText("Total Fuel Consumed").Width(90).Add();
        }))
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

> The code is executed properly without any errors but the Grid is not displayed on the screen.

I suspect the `ej.unobtrusive.min.js` files is not referred in your application.

When the `UnobtrusiveJavascriptEnabled` key of the `appSettings` in web.config is enabled then we should refer the `ej.unobtrusive.min.js` in your layout page to render the Syncfusion MVC controls.

```
<appSettings>

<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />

</appSettings>
```

Please refer to the below help links for the dependent files to render grid.

http://help.syncfusion.com/aspnetmvc/getting-started#to-enable-unobtrusive-option-in-your-application

Answer (score 0):

You need to Render Syncfusion grid to you view page.See the code below

```
@(Html.EJ().Grid<FMSData>("FlatGrid")
        .Datasource((IEnumerable<object>)ViewBag.datasource)
        .SelectionType(SelectionType.Single)

        .Columns(col =>
        {
            col.Field("TotalDistance").HeaderText("Total Distance Travelled").IsPrimaryKey(true).TextAlign(TextAlign.Right).Width(75).Add();
            col.Field("TotalFuelConsumed").HeaderText("Total Fuel Consumed").Width(90).Add();
        })).Render();
```